# Manipulate woocommerc price in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I try to manipulate the calculated price in cart but with no luck...
I hope someone can help me here.

I have found [this](https://wpbeaches.com/adjusting-woocommerce-price-description-acf-custom-field/) article and implemented the code as written on the Page which is to 98% exactly what i searched for. I need to add a cart calculation if the price type is per 100g.

So this is the actual working code:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wb_change_product_html',  10, 2 );
// Adding a custom field to the price markup
function wb_change_product_html( $price, $product ) {
    
    //$wb_price_type = get_field('product_price_type');
    $wb_price_type = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'product_price_type', true);
    
    if($wb_price_type) {
        $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . $price . ' ' . $wb_price_type  . '</span>'; 
    }

    else {
        $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . $price .  '</span>';    
    }

    return $price_html;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'wb_change_product_price_cart', 10, 3 );
// Adding a custom field to the price in the cart
function wb_change_product_price_cart( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    
//$wb_price_type = get_field( 'product_price_type', $cart_item['product_id'] );
$wb_price_type = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_price_type', true );
    
    if ($wb_price_type) {
        $price = $price . ' ' . $wb_price_type; 
    }
    else {
        $price = $price;    
    }
    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'wb_checkout_review', 10, 3 );
// Adding a custom field to the price in the checkout items
function wb_checkout_review ( $quantity, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

//$wb_price_type = get_field( 'product_price_type', $cart_item['product_id'] );
$wb_price_type = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_price_type', true);

    if ( $wb_price_type ) {
        $cart_item = ' ' . sprintf( '× %s ', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . $wb_price_type . '';    
    }

    else {
        $cart_item = ' ' . sprintf( '× %s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '';      
    }
return $cart_item;

}
```

Well i thought its really easy to calculate so i do something like this:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'wb_change_product_price_cart', 10, 3 );
// Adding a custom field to the price in the cart
function wb_change_product_price_cart( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    
//$wb_price_type = get_field( 'product_price_type', $cart_item['product_id'] );
$wb_price_type = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_price_type', true );
    
    if ($wb_price_type) {
        if ($wb_price_type == "per 100g") {
            $price = $price / 100 . ' ' . $wb_price_type;
        }
        else {
            $price = $price . ' ' . $wb_price_type;
        }
    }
    else {
        $price = $price;    
    }
    return $price;
}
```

But this didnt work... i too try to manipulate the price directly but i get anytime 0 in the value of the price...

so i google a little bit more and found [this](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/change-woocommerce-price-display/) article, which makes in the end exactly what i want. in the last print screen we can see that the price will displayed per kg (which is completely fine) and in the calculation it uses an other price (which i try to do with the code above).

i think that the problem is that $price has for example the value "20$" and this is a string and i cannot calculate withe a string. And it makes no sense to split this string there should be an other way.

For better understanding [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7bS7.png) a picture. in the upper part we see the working calculation (which is good) but this is not exactly what i need. in the part down we see that it will only calculate on the calculated price (right side). the left side of the downer part remain with the correct price.

Answer (score 0):

> i think that the problem is that $price has for example the value "20$" and this is a string and i cannot calculate withe a string. And it makes no sense to split this string there should be an other way.

This is true, it's actually a full html string. Try changing the woocommerce_cart_item_price filter to get the price out of string:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'wb_change_product_price_cart', 10, 3);
// Adding a custom field to the price in the cart
function wb_change_product_price_cart($price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)
{
    $wb_price_type = get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'], 'product_price_type', true);
    if ($wb_price_type) {
        if ($wb_price_type == "per 100g") {
            preg_match("/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/", $price, $matches);
            $_price = $matches[0];
            $per100 = $_price / 100;
            $price = $per100 . ' ' . $wb_price_type;
        } else {
            $price = $price . ' ' . $wb_price_type;
        }
    } else {
        $price = $price;
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, i will try it out today and give a short feedback.
Is this the best solution? for me it looks really ugly, is there no direct way to get the price?

Comment: ok tested, calculation works now but on the wrong position... i have added a picture for better understanding